# selling product

Tags: sql

I want to select the top selling products by territory. So far I get the top selling products in each territory

```
SELECT soh.TerritoryID, sod.ProductID, SUM(OrderQty) AS Quantity 
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail sod 
INNER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader soh ON sod.SalesOrderID = soh.SalesOrderID 
GROUP BY sod.ProductID, soh.TerritoryID
```

Which gives me the following results (The image is not complete)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest use of `row_number() over()`. The row_number function provides a sequence of integer values starting at 1 for each "partition" and the row that gets 1 is determined by the ordering within the partition. So here we can give each top selling row a value of 1 by ordering the summed value in descending order. Then we simply filter for only those rows to be returned. Note you need to "nest" the query one level so that you can filter on the generated row numbers.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
          soh.TerritoryID
        , sod.ProductID
        , SUM(OrderQty) AS Quantity
        , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY soh.TerritoryID, sod.ProductID 
                             ORDER BY SUM(OrderQty) DESC
                     ) AS rn
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail sod
    INNER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader soh
        ON sod.SalesOrderID = soh.SalesOrderID
    GROUP BY sod.ProductID
        , soh.TerritoryID
    ) d
WHERE rn = 1
```

see: https://dbfiddle.uk/zuKU9n6o